# Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller and return different Status Codes on different validation fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api2, data-annotations

[HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) is a good but basic article for Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API 2 Controller. But it does not discuss how could we send **custom messages** with **custom HttpStatusCodes**.

For example,
I want to return status code as **499** and message as '**Name Required**' when 'Name' field not provided

I want my HTTP response to look something like

```
HTTP/1.1 **499** 
Bad Request  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Date: Tue, 16 Jul 2013 21:02:29 GMT  
Content-Length: 331

{   
    "Message": "The request is invalid. *Please check*.",
    "ModelState": {
      "product": [
        "Required property 'Name' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 17."
    ],
     "product.Name": [
      "**Name Required**"
    ]
   }
 }
```

I want custom status code and custom message as shown in provided response.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Return standard http code for bad requests and have a custom code either in custom headers or as part of the response body.

Comment: I agree with the others that it is a bad idea, however, you can set the `Response.StatusCode` and return a `JsonResult` with the data you want.

Comment: This is not a great idea as everyone is saying, but if you **really** want to do then you have to do some work around. (Not recommended) 
This may Help:
Just create your own custom class(return model) and loop the ModelState.Keys in 'OnActionExecuting'
which will look like something:
YourObject.Message -> this will be the first message.
foreach (var key in actionContext.ModelState.Keys)
{
foreach (var error in actionContext.ModelState[key].Errors)
{
string message = error.ErrorMessage; -> User these are you want.
string fieldName = key;-> Use this as you want.
}}
Use mode to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a good idea, http status codes have specific meanings and although 499 isn't a standard code nginx does use it and you'll be limited to the gaps that are *currently* in the specs. Just return a custom code in your response body instead.